# Android Mediaplayer Play/Stop help needed

Tags: android, audio, media-player, playback

I am trying to create my first android application and what I'm trying to accomplish here is to play a sound and then stop it via the same button.

It kind of works as it plays the sound when I click it and stops when I click it again but will not play when I click it the third time to start the sound again.

I'm eventually going to have a few sounds in here and so would like to know if how my project is laid out correctly? Can I save some time anywhere? Have I got something the wrong way round?

```
package test.soundy.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer sound;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sound = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.sound1);  

    Button test = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sound.isPlaying()) {
                sound.stop();
            } else {
                sound.start();
            }
        }
    });


}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

WHEN START/PAUSE:

```
if(sound.isPlaying()){
    sound.pause();
}else{
    sound.start();
}
```

WHEN START/STOP:

```
if(sound.isPlaying()) {
    sound.stop();
} else {
    sound.reset();
    sound.setDataSource(yourURL);  //or InputStream etc.
    sound.prepare();
    sound.start();
}
```

Also you can use `sound.seekTo(time)` to skip to a position.
Remember when you want to play a new sound(or restart) you should first `reset`, `setDataSource`, `prepare` and then `start` it.

EDIT: get the FileDescripter

```
AssetManager assetManager=Context.getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("a2.mp3");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

EDIT: I haven't found a way to turn raw file into filedescriptor so I use the static method of MediaPlayer

```
MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this,R.raw.a1);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());
mediaPlayer.start();
private class musicCompletionListener implements OnCompletionListener {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

alse release the mediaplayer when stop it.

Comment: sound.setDataSource(params);

What would I put in there?

Comment: the path of your music like mnt/sdcard/music/xxx.mp3 or an Internet URL, also can be a FileDescriptor like what i edit in the answer

Comment: I dont have a path to the file, I'm bringing the file in via R.raw.sound1 and the setDataSource doesn't seem to want to take a raw input.

Comment: MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.xxx); I wrote a demo and use this code, when end i execute mediaplayer.release(), and new a MediaPlayer next time. But I think it isn't a better way now. consider put the media in asset and use AssetManager as the code above, I'll search if there exist a method to load Raw file.

Comment: This seems a bit much as I'm going to have around 20-30 sounds and can see the code getting out of hand very very quickly with this method, is there no easier way such as making an array of all sounds and then just calling one by ID on a specific button press?

Comment: What if I called my sound like this: `sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);' how do i set the URL? Can i just use `R.raw.sound?`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the MP?

```
if (sound.isPlaying()) {

                sound.stop();
            } else {
                sound.reset();
                sound.prepare();
                sound.start();
            }
```

Edited...
The full state diagram is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: sound.setDataSource(params);

What would I put in there?

Comment: I'm having trouble setting the setDataSource(); parameter what do I need to put into here?

Comment: The updated answer you've posted there is showing problems in Eclipse.

Description Resource Path Location Type
Unhandled exception type IOException SoundBoardActivity.java /SoundBoard/src/soundboard/soundy/com line 29 Java Problem